# How to effectively deal with late events in Azure Data Explorer (Kusto)?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We have an event stream coming from iot devices form partners.

Some of those partners send directly from the device, some centralize collection and send to us in batches.

Some partners send once a day in a burst with all events from previous 24h.

Some partners resume sending after outages and we got events from 3-7 days ago.

The stream have an average of 450 events per second, with 170bytes per event. The peak is 1000 events per second.

The events have a timestamp field and most queries will filter events with timestamp in last 30 days.

My understanding is that Azure data explorer create extents as data arrives. Because of the very late events, I suppose my extents are not optimized for timestamp queries because data from a day will be spread unevenly of several extents, mixed together with other days events.

How to deal effectively with very late events? Is there a way to tell ADX that I plan to query based on a timestamp and get it to self-organize around that for late events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For out-of-order ingestion, you can consider setting up a datetime partition key for the table.

See: [Data partitioning policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy)